# How to find latest documents group by two fields

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I'd like to get the latest documents for each address and country. So in the case bellow, because document 1 and document 2 have the same address and country, I choose the newer one - the one with human1, and the third document is unique. So the result should be two documents, the one with human 1 and human 3.

```
{
  "human": "human1",
  "address": "address"
  "country": "country1"
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-11-08T21:16:20.028Z"),
},
{
  "human": "human2",
  "address": "address"
  "country": "country1"
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-10-08T21:16:20.028Z"),
},
{
  "human": "human3",
  "address": "address"
  "country": "country2"
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-11-08T21:16:20.028Z"),
}
```

My code bellow:

```
public start(){
List<Bson> collect = mongoCurrentAddress
                            .findByHuman(human.getName())
                            .stream().map(this::findCurrentHuman
                            ).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
Bson main = or(collect);
List<Human> humans= humanRepository.filter(main);
}

public Bson findCurrentHuman(Case case
    ) {
        return (match(and(
                regex("address", case.getAddress(),eq("country",case.getCountry())),
        limit(1),
                sort(Sorts.descending("timestamp", TIMESTAMP)));
    }
```

The only way that works for me is to create a separate query for each case (so as many as addresses and country as many queries for the latest documents).

In the above case I get the error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'unknown top level operator: $ limit' on server localhost.localdomain: 27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "unknown top level operator: $ limit", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue", "operationTime": {"$ timestamp": { "t": 1605438274, "i": 1}}, "$ clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$ timestamp": {"t": 1605438274, "i": 1}}, "signature": { "hash": {"$ binary": "W28RhgZ7dgzxcxzcwr0LvNO1QBUuOTU =", "$ type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$ numberLong": "689282134513089875974"}}}}
```

Thanks in advance for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easlily acheive if you use mongo template and aggregation

- `$sort` helps to do DESC order using timestamp
- `$group` and `$first` helps to get the first object
- `$replaceRoot` helps to make the document again to root

The required mongo query is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$address",
        country: "$country"
      },
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uZdtPQZb0_N)**

You need to autowire the Mongo template.

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

The aggregation that you need is ,

```
public List<Object> test(){
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        
        sort(Direction.DESC, "timestamp") ,
        group(  
            Fields.from(
                Fields.field("address", "$address"),
                Fields.field("country", "$country")
        ))
        .first("$$ROOT").as("data"),
         replaceRoot("data")    
        

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Note : I haven't tried the above java code. Hope it should work.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your answer!!!! - but for now I didn't found a way to use MongoTemplate on java EE - that I have to use, I am sorry that I didn't say that earlier, and one more time thanks!